# $x^{15 } +1$ as a product of four factors.

Tags: factoring

How can we write $$x^{15 } +1$$  as a product of four factors.

I can only discern one thing about this,  that $x^{3} +1$,$x^{5 } +1$ and $x^{15 } +1$ are going to be the factors.  But I am unable to move ahead.

Comment: You might want to check the thing you discern...

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695266

Comment: $x^3 +1$ and $x^5 +1$ can be factorized...

Comment: Hint: $x^{15}+1$ is a sum of cubes.

Comment: You can begin by noticing that the fifteenth roots of unity contains the third roots of unity. Performing long division on $(x^{15}+1)/(x^5 +1)$ leads to a simpler expression.

Comment: $(x^{15}+1)\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1$ :p

Answer (score 3):

There just so happens to be this wonderful online calculator known as [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%20x%5E(15)%2B1), and upon putting your problem in, we find

$$x^{15}+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)(x^8+x^7-x^5-x^4-x^3+x+1)$$

Particularly, notice that

$$x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$

$$x^5+1=(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$$

Comment: I'm not up-voting this due to your sarcasm in the beginning of your answer.

Comment: @floorcat and what sarcasm?  WolframAlpha is most definitely a wonderful online calculator.

Comment: It's comforting to read about your complacence with answers when you hit your cap.

Comment: @floorcat I am mildly addicted as the user ranked third this week and fourth this month.  :-)

Comment: Could you please stop it?

Comment: @CatalinZara Stop what?  I'm sorry if I'm self-indulging, I've never hit this much rep in one day before.

Comment: @SimpleArt: I thought this site was about helping others, not about self-indulging or bickering with each other.

Comment: @CatalinZara yes it is, I was just overly excited.  Sorry, and Happy Holidays.

Comment: hey @floorcat, sarcasm, really?? It is okay that you feel something rude here but I do not think that mentioning that "I do not upvote because of your sarcasm" is compleately wrong. There is no harm in making your answer funny.

Comment: @CatalinZara, read the above message it was for you too.

Comment: @floorcat, and I shall upvote it too.  why?? for sarcasm.