# For which $n$ the polynomial $x^n + y^n$ will be irreducible over $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> For which $n$ the polynomial $x^n + y^n$ will be irreducible over $\mathbb Z$?

I think when n is multiple of 2. Can you please correct me if I am wrong and explain why.

Comment: What do you mean by irreducible? Whether it can be further broken down into factors?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695266/factoring-xn-yn-over-the-integers

Comment: yes..Do you know the answer?

Comment: Rohan I have seen already.  I could not understand

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, $x^6 + y^6 = (x^2)^3 + (y^2)^3  = (x^2 + y^2)(x^4 - x^2y^2 + y^4)$

Comment: yesss...U got a counter example. so the answer will be when n is a power of 2. Is not it????

Comment: Yes, $n$ must be a power of $2$. @sani

Comment: @Thomas Ansrews Is it a necessary and sufficient condition for being irreducible of $x^n + y^n$

Comment: Pretty sure it is sufficient, but I'm blanking on how to prove it, at least, without a little abstract algebra.

Comment: When $n$ is a power of two it is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ (see MathChat's answer). But it would be more precise if you specified the field. Over $\Bbb{R}$ it is irreducible only when $n=1$ or $2$, over many other fields it is never irreducible. I guess without a specified field we should assume the rationals

Answer (score 5):

Note that if m is odd, then $x^m+y^m$ is divisible by $x+y$. Thus for $n=2^r⋅m$, where $m>1$ is odd, it follows that $x^n+y^n=(x^{2^r})^m+(y^{2^r})^m$ is divisible by $x^{2^r}+y^{2^r}.$

On the other hand, polynomials of type  $x^{2^r}+y^{2^r}$ are always irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Note that any factorization of $f(x,y)=x^{2^r}+y^{2^r}$ will give us a factorization of    $f(x,1)=x^{2^r}+1$. So it suffices to show that $x^{2^r}+1$
is irreducible. Recall that  cyclotomic polynomials $$\Phi_{n}(x)=\prod_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n \\ (n,k)=1}} (x-e^{2\pi ik/n})$$
 are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Now since

$$\Phi_{2^{r+1}}(x)=x^{2^r}+1,$$
 the claim follows.